# GCC Inline assembly error: invalid instruction suffix for `lidt'

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly, osdev

I am trying to call some assembly code from C. I've recently switched the program from x86 to x86-64 and before it was working. I have this code:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("lidtl (%0)" : : "r" (&idt_reg));
```

Where `&idtreg` is a reference to a struct. Compiling this with GCC gives me this error:

> invalid instruction suffix for `lidt'

When I add a `$` token:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("lidtl $(%0)" : : "r" (&idt_reg));
```

I get this error:

> illegal immediate register operand (%rax)

Why is this problem occurring and how can I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lidtq` if you're in 64-bit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 32-bit code the memory operand for [`LIDT`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt) is 32-bit. In AT&T syntax the `L` instruction suffix forces the assembler to always assume *long* (32-bit). In 64-bit code the memory operands are 64-bit. If you use an instruction suffix then it has to be `Q` (quadword). A quadword is 64-bits.

The assembler is smart enough to know the size of LIDT depending on whether it is generating 32-bit or 64-bit code. The better alternative is to let the assembler deduce the size by leaving off the size in the instruction suffix. Simply use `LIDT` instead. The code could look like:

```
__asm__ ("lidt %0" : : "m" (idt_reg));
```

I've dropped `volatile` as it is implicit when there are no output operands. I use an `m` (memory operand) as a constraint to avoid problems with passing memory addresses through a register. Passing an address through a register requires a `memory` clobber or similar mechanism to ensure the data at that address is available in memory before the inline assembly is emitted. From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

> The **"memory" clobber** tells the compiler that the assembly code
>   performs memory reads or writes to items other than those listed in
>   the input and output operands (**for example, accessing the memory
>   pointed to by one of the input parameters**). To ensure memory contains
>   correct values, GCC may need to flush specific register values to
>   memory before executing the asm.

If you did use an `r` constraint (there is no need to) then the proper code would have been:

```
__asm__ ("lidt (%0)" : : "r" (&idt_reg) : "memory");
```

---

### Footnotes

- By dropping the `L` or `Q` instruction suffix this version should compile whether generating 32-bit or 64-bit programs.
- GCC's inline assembly is [tricky to get right](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm), and if you get it wrong the code generated may not always be what you expect.

Comment: The operand's actuallly 48 or 80 bits, isn't it?  And I don't think there's any operand size suffix for that.  So using either `l` or `q` is a little of a misnomer, but that may just be what gas does.

Comment: @NateEldredge : it is a quirk of GAS syntax for these instructions like LIDT and LGDT. In my footnote I happen to mention that you can drop the suffix as well as GAS can infer the size. I prefer instructions without the suffix unless it can't be inferred

Comment: So to be clear, it's `lidtl` for 32-bit mode where it takes a 48-bit operand, and `lidtq` for 64-bit mode where it takes an 80-bit operand.  And as you say, plain `lidt` also works.

Comment: @NateEldredge : correct. As well, If you use an `L` suffix while generating 64-bit code GNU assembler will  give an error about an illegal suffix for LIDT. If you use a Q suffix while generating 32-bit instructions it will give an error about an invalid suffix. In 32-bit code it is actually valid to also use the `W` suffix but that is a different matter.

Comment: When generating 32-bit instructions the `W` suffix will actually force a 0x66 prefix so that the LIDT instruction will act similar to the real mode or 16-bit protected mode variant where the base address in the IDTR (IDT record) is treated as a 32-bit address where the top 8 bits are set to zero. GAS is odd this way. Note: on an 80286 the IDTR has a 32-bit base address but only the first 3 bytes (24 bits) are read by the processor and the last byte is ignored. NASM syntax for that would be `o16 lidt [mem]` or `lidt [word mem]`

Comment: Effectively in GAS AT&T syntax the suffix denotes the size of the base address in the IDT record (same applies to the GDT record). So I agree it is a misnomer and why I don't like the suffix and removed it from the example I produced. Secondly it allows the code to work with 32-bit/64-bit code. Personally - unless I have a reason to actually override a size in AT&T syntax I let the assembler infer it.